# Adding table values between an undefined list of worksheets that keep data key associations

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Let's imagine you have a totals worksheet and 5 other worksheets that consist of the data for the totals worksheet. Lets also say every worksheet has the same table structure defined on it. For example

```
ID | # played

1  | 4

2  | 1

3  | 11

...
```

How do I make a formula for the totals worksheet so that I know the sum `# played` for ID 1 between all the other worksheets without needing to alter the formula every time a new worksheet is added?

Comment: There's no formula which looks up how many sheets there are in a workbook AFAIK. This would likely require VBA.

Comment: I agree with Jerry. This is not doable with Excel functions only. Do you have any experience in using VBA?

Comment: are you guaranteed that id 1 will be on row 2, id 2 on row 3, etc., on every sheet, or could the positioning change?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution does not require you to alter the existing formula, however it does require some duplication in the sense that you will have to enter the name of the sheet you wish to reference in a cell and when you change a sheet's name you will also have to change the corresponding value in the aforementioned cell.

I do not currently know how to reference sheet names more dynamically with only the basic Excel formulae at one's disposal.

Try this:

Have your sheets ready with information, e.g. name the first sheet "01" and enter your data in columns A and B, e.g.:

```
**Sheet 01**

A1 = 1   B1 = 4
A2 = 2   B2 = 1
A3 = 3   B3 = 11
```

Continue with this format on your other sheets, e.g.:

```
**Sheet 02**

A1 = 1   B1 = 5
A2 = 2   B2 = 6
A3 = 3   B3 = 7
```

and

```
**Sheet 03**

A1 = 1   B1 = 8
A2 = 2   B2 = 9
A3 = 3   B3 = 10
```

Then create the sheet on which you wish to display all this information. For argument's sake, let's call this sheet "Summary".

Then on the Summary sheet, enter the following:

```
**Summary**

A1 =     B1 = 01                                            C1 = 02   D1 = 03
A2 = 1   B2 = =VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT(B$1&"!A:B"),2,FALSE)    C1 =      D1 =   
A3 = 2   B3 =                                               C1 =      D1 =   
A4 = 3   B4 =                                               C1 =      D1 =
```

Then just copy the formulae in B2 to the rest of the cells in which you wish to display your values.

Note than in this example you will have to format the cells in B1:D1 as text, or else Excel will automatically remove the leading 0s and the formula will break. You will probably be using text names for your sheets anyway.

The drawbacks to this solution are:

1. As already mentioned, you have to enter the sheet names manually in the Summary sheet and once a sheet name changes, you have to modify it on the Summary sheet.
2. This solution is not dynamic, taking into account point (1.) and the fact that you have to copy the formula to new cells everytime you wish to expand the range of the summarised values.

Alternatively, you may also wish to consider to replace the formula in B2 in the Summary sheet above with

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT(B$1&"!A:B"),2,FALSE),"")
```

You can then simply fill as much of the Summary sheet as you wish with this formula, which will save you additional work the next time you add more sheets to your workbook.

If your sheet names follow a pattern or if you otherwise know the names of future sheets beforehand, you can even prefill row 1 with these names and the latter formula will still work because it will display nothing in the case that the sheet does not exist, and it will display the relevant value once the sheet with the preknown sheetname has been added to your workbook.